# ViewSonic Monitor on Windows XP

Tags: display, external-display

The Brightness/Contrast Menu is frozen in the center of the screen and the bar keeps flickering up and down between brightness and contrast. As it is in the center of the screen I can't run any diagnostics. I have not seen this problem anywhere. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the menu for the monitor itself which is brought up (various ways) by the buttons on said monitor, so the likelyhood is that a button on the monitor is stuck or sticking,   either physically or just making an electrical connection somehwere.

Pull all the power (from the wall), and see if a full reset would help, when that does not, figure out physically why a button could be stuck. If there is a chance that it got wet/damp then it may dry up given time, and power should not be applied until it is fully dried out.

If the switch itself is broken, or there is to much liquid inside, then you pull the power dissasemble it and diagnose it apart, and make repairs as nessisary.